# The "$k$th diameter" of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

From Menger's theorem, we know that a graph is $k$-connected if and only if it contains $k$ independent paths between any two vertices. Let $G$ be a $k$-connected graph and define the distance between any two vertices $u$ and $v$ to be the length of the longest path among the $k$ shortest independent paths between $u$ and $v$. Define $k$th diameter of $G$, say $D_k(G)$, accordingly to this distance.
We see that $D_1(G)$ is the usual diameter of $G$ and that $D_k(G)$ is an upper bound on the usual diameter of $G$ after removing $k-1$ vertices.

Is there any work done on this quantity? Or something like it?

Comment: Length of the shortest path is defined uniquely, but the path itself is not. Your $k$ shortest independent paths may be selected in a multitude of ways; are you sure that your $k$-distance is well-defined?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Well, are there two ways to order the paths from $u$ to $v$ by length such that the length of the $k$th path from one sequence differs from the other?

Comment: Ordering paths by length is not a big deal, but the _selection_ is. Suppose there are pretty many paths, a lot more than $k$, and many of them are not edge-independent. You can't just pick $k$ shortest paths; nobody said they are independent. Menger's theorem only guarantees that you can select $k$ independent paths. ***How?*** What if there is more than one way to do that?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I see. Maybe we could choose $k$ independent paths such that the length of the longest path among them these is minimized. This way the $k$-distance is well-defined.

Comment: Yeah, now it sounds well-defined, if somewhat computationally intensive. No, I haven't heard anything about it. Let's wait for someone more knowledgeable.